# I can't figure out this equation related to array and loops

Tags: java, arrays, loops, equation

I'm taking an online java course via edx and I was prestented with the following equation.

```
int[] array = new int[] {11, 22, 33, 44, 55};
double average = 0;
for (int element : array){
    average += element;
}
if (array.length > 0){
    average = average / array.length;
}
System.out.println(average);
```

What the questions asks of me is "What does it print?", The answer is 33 but I have spent 3 hours trying to calculate it and I can't get the right answer for the life of me.

Comment: why do you call it "equation"?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: It sums the array and divides by the number of elements. In other words, it calculates the average (as the variable's name suggests). What exactly is your question?

Comment: 11+22+33+44+55 ist 165, 165 /5 = 33

Comment: Did you understand my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I have spent 3 hours trying to calculate it

That's why computers were invented... No but to answer your question:

That is quite simple to calculate. you take the first half and add it to the second, like this:

```
11+55     +     22+44     +     33
```

all of these (apart from the last one) are equal to 66.

thus, you sum 66 twice and add 33, getting 165.

dividing 165 by 5 (number of values in array) gives 33.

The code you showed simply does this calculation hardcore (sums all values one by one and then divides by array length)

Does this explain why the answer is 33?

Comment: The mistake I was doing was dividing it by 4, I thought array length starts from 0 does it not?

Comment: the indices start at 0. the length is normal (normal for normal people, not for programmers XD) the length is the number of values

Comment: Okay that explains everything, thank you very much for your time.